# Prove that $a+b+c=0.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $a, b, c$ are different to each other and

$a^3+ax+y=0$

$b^3+bx+y=0$

$c^3+cx+y=0$

Prove that: $a+b+c=0.$

**Solution in the list:** Notice that $a,b,c$ are roots of the cubic polynomial $d^3+xd+y$ where $x,y$ are constants. Since $a,b,c$ are distinct numbers, they must be the three different roots of the polynomial. However, by Vieta's formulas, the sum of the roots of that polynomial is $\tfrac{-0}{2(1)}=0,$ meaning that $a+b+c=0.$

Question: How do I figure out that certain expressions are roots of polynomials, like this one?

Comment: All a, b, c follow a similar-looking expression. Note that if f(a) = 0, a is a root of f. Since a cubic can have a maximum of 3 distinct roots, we have all our roots as a, b, and c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural solution is the one outlined in @[insipidintegrator](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1062486/insipidintegrator)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714653/prove-that-abc-0#comment9985183_4714653). Namely, note that the $3$ equations are of the form $\,f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0\,$ where $\,f(t) = t^3 + x t + y\,$. Since $\,a,b,c\,$ are mutually distinct, they must be the $3$ roots of the depressed cubic, then it follows by [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) that $\,a+b+c=0\,$.

For an alternate solution, consider the equations as a linear homogeneous system in $\,(1,x,y)\,$.

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a^3 \cdot 1 + a \cdot x + 1 \cdot y = 0
\\ b^3 \cdot 1 + b \cdot x + 1 \cdot y = 0
\\ c^3 \cdot 1 + c \cdot x + 1 \cdot y = 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

The system has the non-trivial solution $\,(1,x,y) \ne (0,0,0)\,$ so its determinant must be zero.

$$
\begin{align}
0 \;&=\; \begin{vmatrix}
a^3 &a &1
\\ b^3 &b &1
\\ c^3 &c &1
\end{vmatrix}
\\ &= a^3 b - a^3 c - a b^3 + a c^3 + b^3 c - b c^3
\\ &= (a - b) (a - c) (b - c) (a + b + c)
\end{align}
$$

Since it is given that $\,(a - b) (a - c) (b - c) \ne 0\,$ it follows that $\,a+b+c = 0\,$.